# Get previous field's value in MySQL trigger

Tags: mysql, trigger

I am using a MySQL database and I have this kind of table.

<kbd>ID</kbd><kbd>Ref</kbd><kbd>Handler</kbd>
<kbd>1</kbd> <kbd>x</kbd>    <kbd>299</kbd>      
<kbd>2</kbd> <kbd>x</kbd>    <kbd>300</kbd>      
<kbd>3</kbd> <kbd>x</kbd>    <kbd>301</kbd>

But I want to create a trigger (before insert) which will set automaticaly the `Handler` field. How to select the previous `Handler` value and just add one with a trigger ?

Is there any better way that storing the result of `SELECT Handler FROM table order by Handler DESC LIMIT 1` and storing this in a VAR.
Is'nt it more efficient to use a magic word like OLD ? Or do I have to use a specific trick for this case?

PS : OLD is not usable in this case ([source](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html))

Comment: Yes, it is possible

Comment: @Phil I edited my question. Sorry ... I do not really know how to proceed and an exemple will be useful

Comment: This post doesn't really show any effort or research on your part.  What have you tried and found to not work?

Comment: @dfundako I projected to use `OLD.table.handler` but I also read this http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html. That say that OLD can not be used during INSERT trigger. So I'm kinda lost

Answer (score 0):

You are treating `Handler` like an `AUTO_INCREMENT`.  Why not get rid of `ID`?  Or use it instead of having an extra column?

**Edit**

Since you want to "reset to 0" the number at the start of the year...  Assuming this is what you want, then converting it to a `TRIGGER` should work:

```
START TRANSACTION;  -- To keep other connections from overlapping
SELECT @year := ...,
       @next := MAX(Handler)+1
    FROM ...;
IF (YEAR(now() > @year) THEN
    SET @next := 0;
ENDIF
INSERT ... @next ...;
```

Comment: Because that's not all the explanation. I just explained what I wanted with the less data possible. In fact the `ref_handler` will reset itself to `0` for each new year